# Query from two tables active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm learning Ruby on Rails, I make a very simple app.
This is the schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160112141616) do

  create_table "cities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "state_id",   null: false
  end

  add_index "cities", ["state_id"], name: "index_cities_on_state_id"

  create_table "states", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

I loaded some states and cities.
And I don't know how to make a query like this using Active Record:

```
SELECT cities.name, states.name FROM cities INNER JOIN states ON cities.state_id = states.id
```

I want to do that to print in a view, all of the cities names with their states names.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

model city.rb:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :states
  validates :state_id, presence: true
end
```

model state.rb:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end
```

cities_controller.rb:

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #@cities = City.all.order(state_id: :asc)
    #@cities = State.joins(:cities).select('cities.name, states.name')
    @cities = City.joins(:states).select('cities.name, states.name')
  end

  def new
    @city = City.new
    @states = State.all.order(name: :asc)
  end

  def create
    @city = City.new(city_params)
    if @city.save(:validate=> true)
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def city_params
    params.require(:city).permit(:name, :state_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will do

```
City.joins(:states).select("cities.name, states.name")
```

> NameError: uninitialized constant City::States

The ***association name*** for the `belongs_to` should be ***singular***, so change `states` to `state` in `city.rb` model

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  validates :state_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Tried your solution and I got this error:

irb(main):004:0> City.joins(:states).select('cities.name, states.name')
NameError: uninitialized constant City::States

Then I tried this:

State.joins(:cities).select('cities.name, states.name')
  State Load (0.1ms)  SELECT cities.name, states.name FROM "states" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."state_id" = "states"."id"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<State id: nil, name: "Santa Fe">, #<State id: nil, name: "Cordoba">, #<State id: nil, name: "Santa Fe">

Comment: @kofran Can you post your model code in the question.